# Any tags below the video tag aren't formatted according to css code

Tags: css, html

I am a complete beginner at html and css. I've trying some of the things and sometimes the css code written sometimes do not work but I don't know why? Where is my fault or error ? Please help me by taking a look at the code and The error in this code is that anything after the video tag isn't changing its color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

        Just some experiments

    </title>
<link href="./c.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="header">

        This is the first and biggest heading

    </h1>

    <h2>

        Now comes the subheading.

    </h2>


    <h3 id="subheading">

        This is the third sub-heading. For this third sub-heading styling I 
used the styling by the adjacent selectors i.e. h2+h3

    </h3>
    <h3 id="subheading">
    This is the fourth sub-heading which has the size as that of the third 
sub-heading.</h3>
    <p>

        This is supposed to be a paragraph. So without any waste of time, 
I'll be pasting LOREM IPSUM.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five 
centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
essentially 
  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset 
sheets 
 containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        <br>
        <span href="css.txt">This is the child of the above paragraph.
     </span><br>
        <span id="vanquish">The name of the class of this span tag is just 
 seriously random and really means nothing but at the same time means a lot 
   to 
 many of the youths.<br> Vanquish is the flagship model of the Aston Martin.
 </span>
        <span href="desertsunset.png" id="vanquish"> Now we are out of the 
 previous span tag.now stepping into new span tag.</span>       
    </p>


    <span> This is written in the span tag which is outside of the 
 paragraph tag which is only the descendent of the body tag.</span>

    <video src="./video.MP4" width=640 height=480 controls>
    Video is not supported by your browser</video> 

    <div id="main">
      <span>Hi this is Srajan</span>
      <span>This is the paragraph inside another paragraph</span>
        <div> This is inside the div tag and now we'll be adding inside another p tag
          <p>So this is actually being written inside two levels deep to the initial p tag. </p>
        </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Now the css code.

```
*{
   font-family: arial;
   color: lightgreen;
   border-radius: 50px;
}

body{
   background-color: black;
}

h2+h3{
   color: aqua;
}

#subheading{
   color: lavenderblush;
}

span[href]{
   color: aqua;
}

#main{
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: monospace;
   color: white;
}
```

As expected the result must have changed the color of the tags below the video but it didn't happen
Please explain why?

Comment: Would you please put it into a Plunker (https://plnkr.co/) and just post appropriate parts of source code here, thank you.

Comment: If you use your browser tools and inspect the relevant elements, you can see the reason. Any element nested inside "main" is going to have its style set by the * CSS styles, because it is not explicitly set. If you change the #main {} portion of your css to #main span {} it shows the text as white. Also if you have the text inside the main div without nesting it inside a span, it shows as white. TL;DR - if you don't explicitly set a style for a specific type of div, then whatever you set in "*" is going to take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem here is not with the `<video></video>` tag. The problem is with

```
 *{
   font-family: arial;
   color: lightgreen;
   border-radius: 50px;
}
```

here you are giving

> color : lightgreen;

to every line of text in your html document. So, when you write `

> `#main{color:white;}`

this applies to only the element you have written it for. In this case only `<div></div>` element gets white colored text. So, when you write `<span>` in `<div>` the `<span>` takes the default color i.e. lightgreen. To understand better you can trying running this code:

```
<div id="main">
this text will be white
<span>this text will be lightgreen</span>
</div>
```

To avoid this problem don't give lightgreen color to the entire document. Rather then make a class

> `.gr{color:lightgreen;}`

and add it to the tag you want to make lightgreen. Or if you want to proceed according to your approach (not recommended), then just change your code

> `#main{color:white}`

to

> `#main > span {color:white}`

this will apply white color to the `<span>` tag.